# Get the last index with same max values in a list

Tags: python

I have the following list:

```
 a = [100, 34, 2, 100]
```

I want the index of the largest value:

```
 $ a.index(max(a))
 Returns: 0
```

What is the Pythonic way of getting the last index (with the largest value) in this case `3`.

(Since the largest value is repeated multiple times.)

Comment: `max((x, i) for i, x in enumerate(a))[1]`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think this might work for you.

```
len(a) - a[::-1].index(max(a)) - 1
```

`a[::-1]` is the Pythonic way to reverse the list, and then the `index` function will find the "first" time that `max(a)` occurs in the reversed list, which will be the last time it occurs in the original list.

Another way to do it could be:

```
def last_max_index2(s):
    m_index = m = None
    for i, elem in enumerate(s):
        if elem >= m:
            m, m_index = elem, i
     return m_index
```

`last_max_index2` has the advantage that it is calculating the max as it goes, and hence only needs one pass over the array. But it's more of an algorithm you would see written in C++ or Java, and less in Python. Often this is correct: the shorter ways that rely on built-ins are better.

However, I think this is a *much* more readable and intuitive approach than any solution using `reduce` or a single-liner with `enumerate` and keys with lambdas. Those solutions will only be readily understandable by very familiar Python programmers.

And a solution like that in the comments is very obfuscated:

```
last_max_index3 = lambda s: max((x, i) for i, x in enumerate(s))[1]
```

I know most folks familiar with Python would disagree, but I think this code is so misdirectional to a Python beginner that it's actually *harmful* to do it this way, regardless of one-liner-ness, use of `enumerate`, and small number of characters typed.

Comment: [`reversed`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#reversed) does not modify the list inplace.

Comment: Well, I believe that's not really Pythonic according to PEP-20 http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0020/ . "Readability counts.". In order to understand your code, we need to think while it's quite obvious when we read the other solutions.

Comment: Besides, the solution walks the list 3 times: to inverse, to find max, and to find the index. And does not work on iterators =)

Comment: You can make the `last_max_index2` function a lot cleaner by initializing `m` and `m_index` to `None`, and removing the outer `if` block. In Python, every number is considered to be larger than `None`.

Answer (score 4):

Seems as simple as:

```
max(enumerate(a), key=lambda x: (x[1], x[0]))[0]
```

[`max()`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#max) takes a *key* parameter. More info in the docs provided.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure that it is very pythonic:

```
l = [100, 34, 2, 100]
>>> reduce(lambda m, p: p if p[1]>=m[1] else m, enumerate(l))
(3, 100)
```

Answer (score 0):

FWIW, here's another option. I dare say more pythonic than the accepted answer

```
max(reversed(xrange(len(a))), key=a.__getitem__)
```